# PHP Class Object Error

Tags: php

```
<?php
  class test{
      private $k=array();

      public function __set($a,$p){
           $this->k[$a]=$p;
      }

      public function __get($a){
            return $this->k[$a];
      }

 }

 $t=new test();
 $t->M="10"; // this works.
 $t->P=array(); // this works.
 $t->P=array("def"=>"456"); // this works.

 $t->P["abc"]="123"; // this doesn't work

 var_dump($t->P);
?>
```

is it possible to do like this $t->P["abc"]="123" or is there any other way to do similar ?

thanks in advance

Comment: The nearest I can think of is that IF your class implements ArrayAccess you could do `$t["abc"]="123";` (with the correct methods).

Comment: Do you have set `$t->P` with an array before writing `$t->P["abc"] = "123";`?

Comment: You need to first add `public $P;` to the body of the class.  If you first account for the variable in such a way, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution with explaination:

```
<?php
class test{
  private $k=array();

  public function __set($a,$p){
       var_dump( "SET: $a=$p" );
       $this->k[$a]=$p;
  }

  public function &__get($a) { // add "&" here to return reference instead of value!
    var_dump( "GET: " . $a );
    return $this->k[$a];
  }

}

$t=new test();
$t->P['abc3'] = "1233"; // triggers GET // gets set by reference
var_dump( $t->P['abc3'] ); // triggers GET for $t->P then returns value of(<ref>)['abc3']

var_dump($t->P); // triggers GET
```

***Output:***

```
string(6) "GET: P"
string(6) "GET: P"
string(4) "1233"
string(6) "GET: P"
array(1) {
  ["abc3"]=>
  string(4) "1233"
}
```